# Animate a border with CSS

Tags: css, border

I want to recreate a CSS animation in my computer (local) but it's not working, when I try the code in Codepen it's working, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code: https://codepen.io/jvera/pen/gXxgXx

```css
{
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #f45e61;
  color: #f45e61;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.draw {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.draw::before, .draw::after {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.draw::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-color: #60daaa;
  border-right-color: #60daaa;
  animation: border 2s infinite;
}
.draw::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: border 2s 1s infinite, borderColor 2s 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes border {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  25% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes borderColor {
  0% {
    border-bottom-color: #60daaa;
    border-left-color: #60daaa;
  }
  50% {
    border-bottom-color: #60daaa;
    border-left-color: #60daaa;
  }
  51% {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<center><h2 class="draw">Titulo</h2><center>
```

I created the two files and put them into the folder, when I run the HTML file I can't see the animation effect (like the demo) so, what can I do? why I'm not seeing the results?

Thanks.

Comment: Try in other browsers and update your browsers to current updated version.

Comment: Is it a typo or you don't have a selector on your first css rule-set on purpose?

Comment: You mention you've created two files and put them into a folder. Does your HTML file reference your CSS file using `<link>`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about your HTML & CSS skills but maybe you are doing something wrong with the linking of your stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

1. Be sure to corectly set the paths (look at this example : [External CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp)) and maybe give a glimpse at the basics of HTML, just in case?

   - [HTML Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp)
2. Also, check if the path is relative or absolute:

**Relative Paths:**

- index.html
- /graphics/image.png
- /help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.html

**Absolute Paths:**

- http://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com/graphics/image.png
- http://www.example.com/help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.html

See the [Full reference about the paths](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).

Hope I helped.

Comment: @Kenyis Check console for errors, if none found - check that css rule applied to `.draw:before` and  `.draw:after` in developer tools.

Comment: You right man! i insert the <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> into the head and works (i did in the body) 

Thanks!!

Comment: you're welcome :). Think about reading the full course to get the good practices when beginning in HTML: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Comment: Also, what i did wrong is copy the SASS plain, now i know i have to compilate :D

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the -WebKit-keyframes feature. It might be your browser. [Link to how to do it](http://www.hubbblog.com/html/usingCSS3Animations)